# Can you check the internet protocol from Django's template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Right now, if I want to check whether the current page is accessed through `http://` or `https://`, I will use the following Javascript in my templates and write html from `document.write`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var protocol = document.location.protocol;
if (protocol == "http:")
    document.write("regular");
else
    document.write("secured");
</script>
```

Is there another way to achieve the above in Django's template without using Javascript?

Comment: if you're only trying to avoid mixed http/https content in your django-generated pages you might consider using protocol relative URLs like src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js".

Answer (score 50, accepted):

if you use a `RequestContext`, you can do the following:

```
<p>You used: {% if request.is_secure %}HTTPS{% else %}HTTP{% endif %}
```

See the [relevant part](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#methods) of the Django documentation.

Comment: you should be able to use: HTTP{% if request.is_secure %}S{% endif %}://{{ request.get_host }} as a shorter option to get the complete base url.

Comment: If you want the base URL to match your current protocol, you should not try to manually switch, but just use `//host.com/path`  This will connect via https when the current connection is secure, and via http when it's not.

Answer (score 40):

Since Django 1.10, you can use:

```
request.scheme
```

in a view, or in a template:

```
{{ request.scheme }}
```

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.scheme)

> A string representing the scheme of the request (http or https usually).

Comment: Hi slavugan; remember that you are answering an old question, so the original question's author has probably long ago solved their problem one way or another. For your answer to be useful, it should be a good answer for other readers searching the site for solutions to similar problems; so I recommend adding a lot more explanation and detail, perhaps with links to official documentation, to really justify why this technique is the best solution to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 9):

You need to enable the appropriate request context processor in your setting.py file:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.core.context_processors.request',)
```

The template will now have a variable named request that contains the current HttpRequest. You can use it to find the protocol:

```
{{ request.is_secure }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `RequestContext` and `request.is_secure` in your template.

One caveat, the process of detecting HTTPS can differ from one server setup to the next so you may have to do a little work to get `request.is_secure` working.  You can get it working either by ensuring that your front end / reverse proxy sets 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST' or by writing a middleware class that is custom to your setup.

Use the [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.1/#id1) SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor [code](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/middleware/http.py?rev=11000#L33) as a starting point, if you go the custom middleware route.